# What is the correct vocalization for Megillas Ester 3:6

Tags: megillat-esther, mesorah-tradition, vowels-nekudot

What is the correct pronunciation for the third word of Megillas Ester [3:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16476/jewish/Chapter-3.htm#showrashi=true&v=6), "‎ויבז בעיניו לשלח יד במרדכי לבדו…‏‎"? Is it with a Patach under the ח or without it?

I have seen many variations in many different prints. Sometimes within the same print (e.g. the [Gutnik Megillah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KT91NE) has nekkudos on the verse and the quote from the verse on the commentary. I happened to look at one on the book store shelf yesterday, and it had with a Patach in the verse, and without in the commentary).

Is it a difference of opinion? If so what is the argument, and who holds each side of it?

Comment: http://tanakh.us/Tanach.xml?Esth3:6-3:6 It's probably just a typo in the manuscript.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Thanks. Doesn't the comment U there indicate there is at least some controversy in the matter?

Comment: AFAIK it indicates that the Leningrad Codex does not have the patach there and everyone agrees that is odd, so it is likely a typo especially because there is no masoretic note in the codex on the word indicating an oddity (such as a ליתא).

Comment: At http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c3303.htm#6 there’s a patach; IIRC they follow the Allepo Codex where possible.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon We currently don't have Aleppo on Esther.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on every online audio I could find, including Chabad.org's [Megillah Trainer](http://www.chabad.org/library/howto/trainer_cdo/aid/2466865/jewish/Megillah-Reading-Trainer.htm#!340927/343664/v556) as well as the comments pointing to [Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c3303.htm#6), it seems that it is uncontroversially with a Patach.

The Leningrad Codex, being the common source for the prints, has it without a Patach, and this is the source of the alternative vocalization, but that seems to be simple error.